# Complex Numbers: Find all natural numbers $k$ such that $z_1^k = z_2^k = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

$z_1 = 1/2(1+i\sqrt{3})$

$z_2 = i$

Find all natural numbers $k$ such that:

$z_1^k = z_2^k = 1$

I thought that as the powers of $i$ are an infinite cycle of $i, \ -1, \ -i, \ 1, \ i, \ -1, \ -i, \ 1, ...$

that $k$ would be $4n $whilst $n \geq 0$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint for the first : $z_1^6=1$ , but $z_1^2\ne 1$ and $z_1^3\ne 1$

Comment: You are right concerning $z_2$

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already found out $z_2^k=1$ for $k=4m$ , $m\in\mathbb N$

We have $$z_1=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{6})+i\sin({\frac{2\pi}{6}})$$

This means, that $z_1^k=1$ for $k=6m$ , $m\in \mathbb N$

Since $lcm(6,4)=12$, we have $z_1^k=z_2^k=1$ for $k=12m$ , $m\in\mathbb N$